# IE9 display only a snippet from an SVG

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9

I have an SVG image in my web page with the size of 1023 x 9430. I only want to display 0 1000 1023 2000. So I change the `height=1000` attribute of my SVG and transform it with `transform="translate(0, -1000)"`. It works fine in FF but IE9 don't translate the SVG. Has anybody an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want `transform` to apply to the outermost svg, the only cross-browser safe way currently is to apply it with css. Firefox is applying the transform in a different way depending on how it was specified, and this is wrong according to WG resolution here: http://www.w3.org/2015/01/08-svg-minutes.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding that `transform` line to the SVG?

If that is not working properly in IE9, you can try the following. Set the `width`, `height`, and `viewBox` as follows:

```
<svg width="1023" height="1000" viewBox="0 1000 1023 1000" ... >
```

(and remove the transform).